# Particle System Resolution

Tags: particles

How can i set particle system resolution more 50?

Paticle system must be:
emit - volume and grid

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution has a hard limit of 250 (when the number is entered manually). If you really need more you could emit from vertices of subdivided plane (<kbd>W</kbd> in *Edit Mode*) and add an array modifier.

[image]

When you don't want to apply the array modifier you should tick the use modifier stack option in the particle settings:

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know why it's limited to 250 ?